# copy multiple text box and organize them in richtext file

Tags: vb.net, clipboard

Currently I am trying to make a form for a helpdesk to easily gather information from them and organize it.  For example in VB I created multiple textbox to ask for user name, building location and room number.

```
Username: John Doe
Building: 1
Room:1A
```

Then I want it to take the information from the text box and organize it into a rich text form in VB so they can see the results.  For example, to show the following

User "John Doe"  is in building "1".  Located in room "A1".

Then copy it to the clip board so they can actually paste it into the support ticketing system by just right click and paste.

Anybody have any reference I can use for this.

Comment: you can paste data in that format to the clipboard (tag) without a special control.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the text from text boxes into a rich text box like this:

```
rtext1.text = "User " & textbox1.text & " is in building " & textbox2.text & _
   "." & vbCrlf & "It is located in room " & textbox3.text & "."
```

One way to copy that to the clipboard is with the clipboard object

```
Clipboard.Clear()
Clipboard.SetText(rtext1.text)
```

Comment: excellent thank you.  Would you happen to know I can add a break?  Kind of like in HTML you would add <BR> to start on the next line.

Comment: Yes, you can use vbCrlf. I'll add an example to the answer.